# Jquery's Ajax and killing SQL process on PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

So I have a script that import a .CSV file, line by line using an "INSERT QUERY" into the database.

I want the user to be able to stop this script anytime.

Here's my AJAX call :

postselect = $.post('addcsvtodatabase.php');

1. **First try** :

Here's my initial handler to stop the script :

```
$('#input').click(function(){
  postselect.abort();
})
```

I noticed the abort() method did stop the script, but the data are still being inserted into the database

1. **Second try** :

From the .php script that is run on the initial AJAX call (addcsvtodatabase.php), I save the process ID of the SQL query like this :

```
    $idconnexion = $connexion->query('SELECT CONNCTION_ID()')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $idconnexion = $idconnexion["CONNECTION_ID()"];
    $_SESSION['idconnexion'] = $idconnexion;
```

Then, I make another ajax call to the abortsql.php script that grab the process ID and try to kill it :

```
$requete = "KILL ".$_SESSION['idconnexion'];
$connexion->query($requete);
```

Here's what the input handler looks like :

```
$('#input').click(function(){
  postselect.abort();
  $.post( "abordsql.php");
})
```

The thing is, I noticed that when I try to abort the import, the abortsql.php is in a "loading" mode and will fire ONLY when the initial ajax call is finished, so it only kill the process when the process is finished, not really usefull.

I tried to kill the process manually on phpmyadmin (I'm getting the same process id from the script and from PHPmyadmin, so no issue there), and it works, it does stop importing the data into the database.

How can I run the abordsql.php script without waiting for the initial AJAX call to end ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `$_SESSION['idconnexion'] = $idconnexion;`, add:

```
session_write_close();
```

The session file is open and locked, so your abort script can't start the session.